# How to set a background image to a linearlayout instead of colour in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, background-image, android-linearlayout

I am trying to set a background image to a linear layout but cannot figure out how to, now it seems like it's not possible. Is it? if not is there a work around? I currently have a colour which looks quite plain, I am looking to get it patterned i.e. check box etc. would android have a built in thing that allows me to replace the colour with some pattern?

Comment: Show us how you've set the color. Show us your java/xml code

Answer (score 1):

Programatically, you can create a reference to that layout

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
```

And set the background drawable to it

```
layout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image, getTheme());
```

Comment: R.drawable.image, getTheme()); Call API >19

Comment: You can use ContextCompat.getDrawable() for lower APIs